# child element occupy the parent height

Tags: css, height

I have a parent element with min-height and child with height 100%. I want child element to occupy complete height of parent and in case of overflow I want a scroll. Please find the sample fiddle with my requirement.

[Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/Manasa_Lingamallu/425x08ka/2/)

```css
.parent {
  min-height: 200px;
  background-color: tomato;
  width: 100%;
}

.child {
  background-color: green;
  color: #fff;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">Test child element height</div>
</div>
```

Comment: you would need your parent to have a max height too if you want overflow to scroll, otherwise it would not overflow, it would just grow

Answer (score 0):

You would need to have a height set on your parent too otherwise it can't overflow, it will just keep growing.  Below I have set it to 100% and also given `overflow: auto` to your child:

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.parent {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 200px;
  background-color: tomato;
  width: 100%;
}

.child {
  background-color: green;
  color: #fff;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.scroll-content {
  padding-top: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    Test child element height
    <div class="scroll-content">toggle full page a play with height to see this scroll when the screen gets too small or take up full parent height if not</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can set an `height` to the child instead and use `overfow-y:scroll`.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.parent {
  background-color: tomato;
  width: 100%;
}
.child {
  background-color: green;
  color: #fff;
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    Test child element height
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    some text
  </div>
</div>
```

You can also remove the parent if you don't need it for something else.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
div {
  background-color: green;
  color: #fff;
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Test child element height
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  some text
</div>
```